# Can I play the same Starbound character on multiple computers?

Tags: starbound

Is there currently a way to play the same character in the same universe on multiple computers?  I would like to be able to take my game with me to campus or the living room, but do most of my play on my desktop.

Clarification:  Not concurrently.  I would play on my desktop, save and exit, then resume play on my laptop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, just take a backup of your universe and player folders and restore them on another computer. It should keep all your characters, spaceships and buildings intact. You should find both folders directly under your Starbound folder.

Comment: This will probably change after we get past the character wipes, it should be trivial to move the save files to the steamcloud synced folder.

Comment: You can use [Game Saver Manager](http://www.gamesave-manager.com/) in order to do that.

Comment: I've been using Dropbox for now.

Comment: Another alternative is to use BTSync, that way nothing will be uploaded online if you're playing on computers in the same network.